# How to dynamically add certificates on Amazon Cloud to enable multidomain SSL comunication?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I need to manage multiple SSL Certificates on Amazon ELC instances farm, running multiple domains on a Ruby on Rails application.

The problem is that we need to dynamically add new certificates to the instances or balancer to provide SSL. We need to do it every time a new domain is directed to our application, or when a domain already linked is selected to enable SSL and a new certificate is uploaded.

At this moment we have one Elastic Load Balancer and 8 instances(and counting) behind it. But one ELB only allows one certificate, and create one balancer per domain is not a desirable option.

I'm thinking in complement the ELB with HAProxy to share the same IP/Port using SNI, but I'm not sure if this is possible and works on all browsers.
We tried to enable SSL on the instances, but required to use as many ports as certificates so it's not easy to manage, and still have to add more balancers.

What alternatives would you try?

In your opinion, what's the best way to dynamically add Certificates?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a SAN Cert http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm
The maintenance here is that every time you add a domain you'll need to have them reissue the certificate. You set ELB in tcp mode and terminate at the server level.

Comment: Are you sure need to terminate the server and not the ELB? See http://hungrygeek.holidayextras.co.uk/ops/2012/03/16/ssl-san-termination-in-the-amazon-cloud-with-elbs/